# High number causes seg fault

Tags: c++, c, memory

This bit of code is from a program I am writing to take in x col and x rows to run a matrix multiplication on CUDA, parallel processing. The larger the sample size, the better.

I have a function that auto generates x amount of random numbers.

I know the answer is simple but I just wanted to know exactly why. But when I run it with say 625000000 elements in the array, it seg faults. I think it is because I have gone over the size allowed in memory for an int.

What data type should I use in place of int for a larger number?
This is how the data is being allocated, then passed into the function.

```
a.elements = (float*) malloc(mem_size_A);
```

where

```
int mem_size_A = sizeof(float) * size_A; //for the example let size_A be 625,000,000
```

Passed:

```
randomInit(a.elements, a.rowSize,a.colSize, oRowA, oColA);
```

What the randomInit is doing is say I enter a 2x2 but I am padding it up to a multiple of 16. So it takes the 2x2 and pads the matrix to a 16x16 of zeros and the 2x2 is still there.

```
void randomInit(float* data, int newRowSize,int newColSize,  int oldRowSize, int oldColSize)
{
    printf("Initializing random function. The new sized row is %d\n", newRowSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < newRowSize; i++)//go per row of new sized row.
    {
        for(int j=0;j<newColSize;j++)
        {
            printf("This loop\n");
            if(i<oldRowSize&&j<oldColSize)
            {
                data[newRowSize*i+j]=rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;//brandom();
            }
            else
                data[newRowSize*i+j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

I've even ran it with the printf in the loop. This is the result I get:

```
Creating the random numbers now
Initializing random function. The new sized row is 25000
This loop
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: How / where is `data` defined ?

Comment: Where are you mallocing the data-array? It's probably too small

Comment: Please show the code that calls this function. In fact, please produce a small, complete program that demonstrates your seg fault and paste there into your question. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: At least on my system, 625000000 floats = 2500000000 bytes = 2384 MB. Are you really surprised?

Comment: You're overflowing `data`. You can't just decide to access memory you haven't allocated.

Comment: I think it's an overflow of data. What is the size of data ?

Comment: I've updated it to show how I initialised the size of data.

Comment: malloc and C++ take don't seem to fit well together

Comment: @PlasmaHH what should I use? New?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin, I'm running on a machine that has 8GB of ram

Comment: @Dan: more likely an std::vector<float>

Comment: @PlasmaHH I have to use an array. I later pass the array to a CUDA device where only C code can be executed.

Comment: @Dan: Will that device take ownership over the memory? otherwise just a `float*` to the data would suffice, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm not positive, however the array has not even been created prior to the segfault. It enters the first loop, then enters the second loop, prints to the screen "For Loop" then immediately seg faults. This leads me to believe it's an error in this code rather than anything to do with CUDA.

Comment: Considering "The new sized row is 25008", the obvious question is: what is `newColSize`? Also, have you checked `data != NULL`?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is 25000, the 8 is apart of the padding needed to be a multiple of 16. I just have it there to display it for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory allocation for `data` is probably failing.

Fortunately, **you almost certainly don't need to store a large collection of random numbers.**

Instead of storing:

```
data[n]=rand() / (float)RAND_MAX
```

for some huge collection of `n`, you can run:

```
srand(n);
value = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
```

when you need a particular number and you'll get the same value every time, as if they were all calculated in advance.

Comment: I'm kind of lost with your explanation. I have to pass the array later to another function. How does seeding it at the location I want mean that the value will be at that location for the array?

Comment: @Dan, perhaps you could amend your question with an explanation to why you **need 5 billion random bits**.  It an unusual thing to need, in my experience.  You may find that you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: This bit of code is from a program I am writing to take in x col and x rows to run a matrix multiplication on CUDA, parallel processing. The larger the sample size, the better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going past the value you allocated for `data`.  when you're newrowsize is too large, you're accessing unallocated memory.

remember, `data` isn't infinitely big.

Answer (score -2):

Well the real problem is that, if the problem is really the integer size used for your array access, you will be not able to fix it. I think you probably just have not enough space in your memory so as to store that huge number of data.

If you want to extends that, just define a custom structure or class if you are in C++. But you will loose the O(1) time access complexity involves with array.